# How to save dataframe geometry to a shapefile in R

Tags: r, dataframe, shapefile

I want to save `route_dhdb_sf` in SHP file, it looks like this :

[image: route_dhdb_sf table]

My problem is the geometry column.
The R code :

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(stplanr)

# Read shapefile
nl_rails_sf <- sf::st_read("~/netherlands-railways-shape/railways.shp")

# Data frame with station locations
stations_df <- data.frame(station = c("Den Haag", "Den Bosch"), 
                          lat = c(52.080276, 51.690556), 
                          lon = c(4.325, 5.293611)) 

# Create sf object 
stations_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(stations_df, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)  

# Find shortest route
slnetwork <- SpatialLinesNetwork(nl_rails_sf)
find_nodes <- find_network_nodes(sln = slnetwork, 
                                 x = stations_df$lon, 
                                 y = stations_df$lat, 
                                 maxdist = 2e5)
route_dhdb_df <- data.frame(start = find_nodes[1], end = find_nodes[2])
route_dhdb_sf <- sum_network_links(sln = slnetwork, routedata = route_dhdb_df)
```

How do I save this `route_dhdb_sf` to a shape file?
#Code of mharinga

Answer (score 2):

Normally you can use:

```
sf::st_write(route_dhdb_sf,"~/netherlands-railways-shape/route_dhdb_sf.shp")
```

If you tried it, and if it did not work (you got an error message), you can try to save to other formats e.g. geosjon by editing the suffix like this:

```
sf::st_write(route_dhdb_sf,"~/netherlands-railways-shape/route_dhdb_sf.geojson")
```